# Filling a default value if count is less than threshold in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['john','sam','john','john','dean','dean','maggi',
              'ram','maggi','ana','sam','sam']
df['pt'] = [23, 32, 45, 65, 65, 45, 32, 45, 90, 10, 32, 22]
```

I want to replace a name by other if name appears only once in name column.

So my output would be:

```
     name  pt
0    john  23
1     sam  32
2    john  45
3    john  65
4    dean  65
5    dean  45
6   maggi  32
7   other  45
8   maggi  90
9   other  10
10    sam  32
11    sam  22
```

In my original data, values are in hundreds so using
`df.replace` or `map` is not feasible.

`np.where` works only with binary column. So I'm stuck here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for select all unique rows or use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` for more general solution with specifying threshold:

```
df['name'] = np.where(~df['name'].duplicated(keep=False), 'other', df['name'])
```

Or:

```
df['name'] = np.where(df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size') == 1, 'other', df['name'])
print (df)
     name  pt
0    john  23
1     sam  32
2    john  45
3    john  65
4    dean  65
5    dean  45
6   maggi  32
7   other  45
8   maggi  90
9   other  10
10    sam  32
11    sam  22
```

Another solution, thanks @Jon Clements:

```
df.name.where(df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size') > 1, 'other', inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks. It  worked. Won't be able to use 1st one though as threshold I'm using in actual is 5.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - Yes, then second solution need with `transform`.

Comment: @jezrael I had `df.name.where(df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size') > 1, 'other', inplace=True)` - not sure if you want to add that as a possible option - not sure how performant it is

Comment: @JonClements -I add it to answer, hard question, it depends of data.

Comment: Can someone comment on complexity of Pandas `groupby`? If O(n) [where *n* is number of rows], then this would work. `sort=False` can, of course, be used to avoid sorting keys.

Comment: Umm... another random idea: `df.name.apply(lambda name, counts=Counter(df.name): name if counts[name] > 1 else 'other')`

Comment: timeit wise (on a very slow machine): `np.where` - *1.02 ms ± 9.89 µs per loop*, `df.name.where`: *1.45 ms ± 50.8 µs per loop* and `collections.Counter`: *162 µs ± 2.25 µs per loop*

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorised solution using [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df['name'].value_counts(sort=False)
df.loc[df['name'].isin(s[s == 1].index), 'name'] = 'other'

print(df)

     name  pt
0    john  23
1     sam  32
2    john  45
3    john  65
4    dean  65
5    dean  45
6   maggi  32
7   other  45
8   maggi  90
9   other  10
10    sam  32
11    sam  22
```

**Performance benchmarking**

If you have many repeated names, to improve performance you can use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-data). Timings below on Python 3.6, Pandas 0.19.

```
def jpp(df):
    s = df['name'].value_counts(sort=False)
    df.loc[df['name'].isin(s[s == 1].index), 'name'] = 'other'
    return df

def jez(df):
    df['name'] = np.where(df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size') == 1, 'other', df['name'])
    return df

def jon(df):
    df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda name, counts=Counter(df['name']): name if counts[name] > 1 else 'other')
    return df

assert jpp(df).equals(jez(df))
assert jpp(df).equals(jon(df))

%timeit jpp(df)  # 49.4 ms per loop
%timeit jez(df)  # 56.2 ms per loop
%timeit jon(df)  # 274 ms per loop
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john','sam','john','john','dean','dean','maggi',
                            'ram','maggi','ana','sam','sam'],
                   'pt': [23, 32, 45, 65, 65, 45, 32, 45, 90, 10, 32, 22]})

df['name'] = df['name'].astype('category')
df['name'] = df['name'].cat.add_categories('other')

df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df.iloc[:5]]*100000)])
```